# How to set action for previous and next controls in ExoPlayer?

Tags: java, android, exoplayer, foreground-service, android-service-binding

I am making a audio player app. I created a service for audio player and playback notification. I am facing problem with the previous/next buttons in the Player as well as the playback notification.

1. The previous/next buttons in the audio playback notification just restarts the playback and do not change the song/audio file. Other controls work well.
2. The previous/next buttons in the audio player (using exoplayer) change and play the next/previous file but the player artwork (image for audio file) do not change. Also, the play/pause button remains in paused state and when pressed, it plays a different file.
   Here is the code for the AudioActivity and AudioService-
   **AudioActivity.java**

```
package com.example.videoplayer.audio;

import static com.example.videoplayer.RecyclerViewClasses.MediaFilesActivity.FOLDER_NAME_KEY;
import static com.example.videoplayer.RecyclerViewClasses.MediaFilesActivity.MY_PREF;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.ServiceConnection;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.PopupMenu;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.example.videoplayer.MediaFiles;
import com.example.videoplayer.MediaPlayer.PlaylistDialog;
import com.example.videoplayer.R;
import com.example.videoplayer.RecyclerViewClasses.MediaFilesAdapter;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.PlaybackException;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.Player;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.SimpleExoPlayer;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.TracksInfo;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.util.Util;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class AudioActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private static final String TAG = AudioActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    private static final String CHANNEL_ID = "channel_id";

    PlayerView playerView;
    SimpleExoPlayer player;
    //public static SimpleExoPlayer player;
    RelativeLayout root;
    ImageView audioBack, audioList, menu_more;
    ImageView nextButton, previousButton;

    TextView playlistTitle, title;
    ArrayList<MediaFiles> mAudioFilesArrayList;
    int position;
    MediaFilesAdapter mediaFilesAdapter;
    String audioTitle;
    String listTitle;
    private AudioService mService;
    private boolean mBound = false;
    private Intent serviceIntent;

    private ServiceConnection mServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder iBinder) {
            AudioService.LocalBinder binder = (AudioService.LocalBinder) iBinder;
            mService = binder.getService();
            mBound = true;
            Log.i(TAG + " ###", "in onServiceConnected: calling initializePlayer()");
            initializePlayer();
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName componentName) {
            mBound = false;
        }
    };

    void initializePlayer() {
        if (mBound) {
            Log.i(TAG + " ###", "initializePlayer() called");
            player = mService.getplayerInstance();
//            playerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//            player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
            playerView.setPlayer(player);
//            player.play();
//            player.seekTo(position, C.TIME_UNSET);
            playError();
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("UseCompatLoadingForDrawables")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i(TAG + " ###", "onCreate() called");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setFullScreen();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_audio_player);
        try {
            getSupportActionBar().hide();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            Log.e(TAG + " ###", "in VideoPlayerActivity: " + e);
        }

        playerView = findViewById(R.id.exoplayer_view_audio);

        Log.i(TAG + " ###", "default artwork set in onCreate()");


        root = findViewById(R.id.root_layout_audio);
        audioBack = findViewById(R.id.audio_back_audio);
        audioList = findViewById(R.id.audio_list);
        nextButton = findViewById(R.id.exo_next);
        previousButton = findViewById(R.id.exo_prev);
        playlistTitle = findViewById(R.id.playlistTitle);
        title = findViewById(R.id.audiofile_title);
        menu_more = findViewById(R.id.audio_more);

        SharedPreferences preferences = this.getSharedPreferences(MY_PREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        listTitle = preferences.getString(FOLDER_NAME_KEY, "DEFAULT_FOLDER_NAME");

        position = getIntent().getIntExtra("position", 1);
        audioTitle = getIntent().getStringExtra("media_title");
        Bundle b = getIntent().getBundleExtra(this.getString(R.string.bundle));
        mAudioFilesArrayList = b.getParcelableArrayList(this.getString(R.string.media_array_list));

        Log.i(TAG + " ###", "position=" + position);
        Log.i(TAG + " ###", "is mAudioFilesArrayList null " + (mAudioFilesArrayList == null));
        if (mAudioFilesArrayList == null)
            return;


        audioList.setOnClickListener(this);
        nextButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        previousButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        audioBack.setOnClickListener(this);
        menu_more.setOnClickListener(this);


        startServiceIntent();

    }

    void startServiceIntent() {
        Log.i(TAG + " ###", "entered startServiceIntent");
        serviceIntent = new Intent(this, AudioService.class);
        Log.i(TAG + " ###", "position=" + position);
        serviceIntent.putExtra("position", position);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        Log.i(TAG + " ###", "is mediaArrayList null " + (mAudioFilesArrayList == null));
        bundle.putParcelableArrayList(this.getString(R.string.media_array_list), mAudioFilesArrayList);
        serviceIntent.putExtra("bundle", bundle);
        Util.startForegroundService(this, serviceIntent);
        playerView.setControllerHideOnTouch(false);
        playerView.setUseController(true);
        playerView.setControllerShowTimeoutMs(0);
        playerView.showController();
        playerView.setControllerAutoShow(true);

        setUI();


    }

    private void playError() {
        Log.i(TAG + " ###", "entered the playError() method()");
        //Player.EventListener is deprecated
        player.addListener(new Player.Listener() {

            @Override
            public void onTracksInfoChanged(@NonNull TracksInfo tracksInfo) {
                Player.Listener.super.onTracksInfoChanged(tracksInfo);
                Toast.makeText(AudioActivity.this, "TrackInfoChanged", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            @Override
            public void onPlayerError(@NonNull PlaybackException error) {
                Toast.makeText(AudioActivity.this, "Audio Playing Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
    }

    private void setFullScreen() {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Log.i(TAG + " ###", "entered onStart()");
        getApplicationContext().bindService(serviceIntent, mServiceConnection, 0);
        initializePlayer();
        setUI();
    }

    void setUI() {
        Log.i(TAG + " ###", "entered setUI()");
        title.setText(audioTitle);
        playlistTitle.setText(listTitle);
        Log.i(TAG + " ###", "text set in setUI()");
        //playerView.setDefaultArtwork(AppCompatResources.getDrawable(this,R.drawable.ic_sharp_music_note_24));
        //playerView.setUseArtwork(true);


    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.i(TAG + " ###", "onResume() called");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {

        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        Log.i(TAG + " ###", "onStop() called, unbinding service!");

        getApplicationContext().unbindService(mServiceConnection);

        mBound = false;
        finish();
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Log.i(TAG + " ###", "entered onClick() method");
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.exo_play:
                player.play();
                break;
            case R.id.exo_pause:
                player.pause();
                break;
            case R.id.exo_next:
                try {
                    player.stop();
                    stopService(serviceIntent);
                    position++;
                    audioTitle = mAudioFilesArrayList.get(position).getTitle();
                    title.setText(audioTitle);
                    startServiceIntent();
                    initializePlayer();
                    player = mService.getplayerInstance();
                    //playerView.setPlayer(null);
                    playerView.setPlayer(player);
                    
                    playError();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "No next audio file", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    position--;
                }
                break;
            case R.id.exo_prev:
                Log.i(TAG + " ###", "previous button clicked!");
                try {
                    player.stop();
                    Log.i(TAG+" ###","player stopped!");
                    stopService(serviceIntent);
                    position--;
                    audioTitle = mAudioFilesArrayList.get(position).getTitle();
                    title.setText(audioTitle);
                    startServiceIntent();
                    //initializePlayer();
                    player=mService.getplayerInstance();
                    //playerView.setPlayer(null);
                    playerView.setPlayer(player);
                    
                    playError();


                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "No previous Video", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    position++;
                }

                break;
            case R.id.audio_back_audio:
                if (player != null)
                    //player.release();
                    finish();
                break;
            case R.id.audio_list:
                PlaylistDialog playlistDialog = new PlaylistDialog(mAudioFilesArrayList, mediaFilesAdapter);
                playlistDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), playlistDialog.getTag());
                break;
            case R.id.audio_more:
                PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(this, menu_more);
                MenuInflater inflater = popupMenu.getMenuInflater();
                inflater.inflate(R.menu.actions_video, popupMenu.getMenu());
                popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
                        int id = menuItem.getItemId();
                        switch (id) {
                            case R.id.share_file:
                                Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                                String filepath = mAudioFilesArrayList.get(position).getPath();
                                Uri uri = Uri.parse(filepath);
                                shareIntent.setType("/");
                                shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
                                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share File using"));
                                break;
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });
                popupMenu.show();

                break;
        }

    }
}
```

**AudioSerivce.java**

```
package com.example.videoplayer.audio;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

import com.example.videoplayer.MediaFiles;
import com.example.videoplayer.R;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.C;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.MediaItem;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.PlaybackParameters;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.Player;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.SimpleExoPlayer;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.audio.AudioAttributes;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ConcatenatingMediaSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.MediaSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ProgressiveMediaSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerNotificationManager;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultDataSource;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class AudioService extends Service {
    private static final String TAG = AudioService.class.getSimpleName();
    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();
    private SimpleExoPlayer player;
    private int position;
    PlaybackParameters parameters;
    private ArrayList<MediaFiles> mAudioFilesArrayList;
    private PlayerNotificationManager.Builder playerNotificationManagerBuilder;
    private PlayerNotificationManager playerNotificationManager;
    ConcatenatingMediaSource concatenatingMediaSource;
    private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    private static final String CHANNEL_ID = "channel_id";

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.i(TAG+" ###","onDestroy() called");
        releasePlayer();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private void releasePlayer() {

        if (player != null) {
            Log.i(TAG+" ###","Player!=null and releasePlayer called");
            playerNotificationManager.setPlayer(null);
            player.release();
            player = null;
        }
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    public SimpleExoPlayer getplayerInstance() {
        Log.i(TAG+" ###","getplayerInstance() called: "+(player==null));
        if (player == null) {
            startPlayer();
        }
        return player;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
//        try {
            Bundle b = intent.getBundleExtra(this.getString(R.string.bundle));
            String name=this.getString( R.string.media_array_list);
            mAudioFilesArrayList = b.getParcelableArrayList(this.getString( R.string.media_array_list));
//        }
//        catch(Exception e)
//        {
//            Log.e(AudioService.class.getSimpleName()+" ###",e.toString());
//            stopSelf();
//        }
        position = intent.getIntExtra("position", 1);
        Log.i(TAG+"###"," in onStartCommand()");
        Log.i(TAG+" ###","is mediaArrayList null"+(mAudioFilesArrayList==null));
        Log.i(TAG+" ###","position="+position);
        if (player == null) {
            Log.i(TAG+" ###","Player is null, in onStartCommand calling startPlayer()");
            Log.i(TAG+" ###","is mediaArrayList null"+(mAudioFilesArrayList==null));
            Log.i(TAG+" ###","position="+position);
            startPlayer();
        }
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    private void startPlayer() {
        Log.i(TAG+" ###","entered startPlayer()");
        Log.i(TAG+" ###","is mediaArrayList null"+(mAudioFilesArrayList==null));
        Log.i(TAG+" ###","position="+position);
        final Context context = this;
        createNotificationChannel();
        playerNotificationManagerBuilder = new PlayerNotificationManager.Builder(context, NOTIFICATION_ID, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setRewindActionIconResourceId(R.drawable.ic_rewind)
                .setNextActionIconResourceId(R.drawable.ic_next)
                .setPreviousActionIconResourceId(R.drawable.ic_previous)
                .setSmallIconResourceId(R.drawable.ic_sharp_music_note_24);
        playerNotificationManagerBuilder.setPlayActionIconResourceId(R.drawable.ic_play);
        playerNotificationManagerBuilder.setPauseActionIconResourceId(R.drawable.ic_pause);
        playerNotificationManagerBuilder.setFastForwardActionIconResourceId(R.drawable.ic_fast_forward);

        playerNotificationManagerBuilder.setMediaDescriptionAdapter(new PlayerNotificationManager.MediaDescriptionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public CharSequence getCurrentContentTitle(Player player) {
                return mAudioFilesArrayList.get(position).getTitle();
            }

            @Nullable
            @Override
            public PendingIntent createCurrentContentIntent(Player player) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, AudioActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("position", position);
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putParcelableArrayList(context.getString( R.string.media_array_list), mAudioFilesArrayList);
                intent.putExtra("bundle",bundle);

                return PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT|PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
            }

            @Nullable
            @Override
            public CharSequence getCurrentContentText(Player player) {
                return "Summary";
            }

            @Nullable
            @Override
            public Bitmap getCurrentLargeIcon(Player player, PlayerNotificationManager.BitmapCallback callback) {
                int window=player.getCurrentMediaItemIndex();
                Log.i(TAG+"###","in getCurrentLargeIcon: window="+window);
                    return null;
//                return getCurrentLargeIcon(player,callback);
            }

        });
        playerNotificationManagerBuilder.setNotificationListener(new PlayerNotificationManager.NotificationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onNotificationCancelled(int notificationId, boolean dismissedByUser) {
                Log.i(TAG+" ###","onNotificationCancelled called!");
                stopSelf();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNotificationPosted(int notificationId, Notification notification, boolean ongoing) {
                startForeground(notificationId, notification);
                Log.i(TAG+" ###","startForeground() in onNotificationPosted!");
            }
        });
        playerNotificationManager=playerNotificationManagerBuilder.build();

        Log.i(TAG+" ###","startPlayer() called");
        String path = mAudioFilesArrayList.get(position).getPath();
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);
//        PlayerView.Builder builder = new ExoPlayer.Builder(this);
//        builder.setSeekForwardIncrementMs(5000);
//        builder.setSeekBackIncrementMs(5000);
//        player = builder.build();
        SimpleExoPlayer.Builder builder = new SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(this);
        builder.setSeekForwardIncrementMs(10000);
        builder.setSeekBackIncrementMs(10000);
        player = builder.build();


        DefaultDataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSource.Factory(this);

        concatenatingMediaSource = new ConcatenatingMediaSource();
        for (int i = 0; i < mAudioFilesArrayList.size(); i++) {
            new File(String.valueOf(mAudioFilesArrayList.get(i)));
            MediaSource mediaSource = new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
                    .createMediaSource(MediaItem.fromUri(Uri.parse(String.valueOf(uri))));
            concatenatingMediaSource.addMediaSource(mediaSource);
        }

        player.setMediaSource(concatenatingMediaSource);
        AudioAttributes audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setUsage(C.USAGE_MEDIA)
                .setContentType(C.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
                .build();
        player.setAudioAttributes(audioAttributes, true);
        player.setPlaybackParameters(parameters);
        player.prepare();

        player.play();
        player.seekTo(position,C.TIME_UNSET);

        //player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
        playerNotificationManager.setPlayer(player);
        playerNotificationManager.setUseNextAction(true);
        playerNotificationManager.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_sharp_music_note_24);
        playerNotificationManager.setColorized(true);
        playerNotificationManager.setUseChronometer(true);
        playerNotificationManager.setColor(R.color.teal_200);
        playerNotificationManager.setUseChronometer(true);
        playerNotificationManager.setUseRewindAction(true);
        playerNotificationManager.setUseFastForwardAction(true);
        playerNotificationManager.setUsePlayPauseActions(true);
        Log.i(TAG+" ###","returning from startPlayer()");
    }

    private void createNotificationChannel() {
        Log.i(TAG+" ###","createNotificationChannel()");
        // Create the NotificationChannel, but only on API 26+ because
        // the NotificationChannel class is new and not in the support library
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            CharSequence name = getString(R.string.channel_name);
            String description = getString(R.string.channel_description);
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
            channel.setDescription(description);
            // Register the channel with the system; you can't change the importance
            // or other notification behaviors after this
            NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
    }
    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        public AudioService getService() {
            return AudioService.this;
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me in finding the problem and resolving it.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the use of MediaSessionCompat is essential for an audio app. A very good instructions can be found [here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/background-audio-in-android-with-mediasessioncompat--cms-27030).
I hope this helps you.

GGK